# How to pull values from one gridview and insert them into another gridview asp vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I currently have two gridviews one coming from SQL connection the other comes from a OLEDB2 connection. I can run through these gridviews and check if one contains values that the other does not.

My question is there a way that when i find these values i can put them into a final gridview to show the common values between the other two gridviews?

thanks for your help in advance,
this is what i have so far.

```
    Puclic Sub CompareDB()
    Dim missingRecords As New DataTable
    missingRecords = GridView1.DataSource.clone()
    GridView3.DataSource = missingRecords
    GridView3.DataBind()

    Dim V1 As String = ""
    Dim V2 As String = ""
    Dim msg As String = ""
    Dim check As Boolean = False
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
        check = False
        For Each rw As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            V1 = row.Cells(0).Text
            V2 = rw.Cells(0).Text

            V2 = Replace(V2, " ", "")
            If V1 = V2 Then
                check = True
                ' if check is true 
                ' insert the value V1 and V2 into GridView 3

                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If check = False Then
            msg = msg & V1 & " -999 "
        End If
    Next
    msg = msg & "------------------------------------------------------------------ -999 "
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        check = False
        For Each rw As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows

            V1 = row.Cells(0).Text
            V2 = rw.Cells(0).Text

            V1 = Replace(V1, " ", "")
            If V1 = V2 Then
                check = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If check = False Then
            msg = msg & V1 & " -999 "
        End If
    Next
    ' after all checks complete, inserts the the non common values
    ' into gridview3
    ' EXAMPLE: GridView3
    ' gridview1 | gridview2
    ' v1        | V2
    ' v1        | V2
    ' non common|
    '           | non common

    msg = Replace(msg, "-999", "<br />")



    ' used to output for testing
    Label1.Text = msg
End Sub`
```

Comment: You can use LINQ to compare the 2 data sets create a new data set to populate the new gridview with the new data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked out. posting the solution to my problem below.

```
 Public Sub compareDBs()

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt.Columns.Add("FromPARC", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("FromJDE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    Dim myrow As DataRow

    Dim V1 As String = ""
    Dim V2 As String = ""
    Dim msg As String = ""
    Dim check As Boolean = False

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
        check = False
        For Each rw As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            V1 = row.Cells(0).Text
            V2 = rw.Cells(0).Text
            V2 = Replace(V2, " ", "")
            If V1 = V2 Then
                check = True
                myrow = dt.NewRow
                myrow("FromPARC") = V1
                myrow("FromJDE") = V2
                dt.Rows.Add(myrow)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If check = False Then
            myrow = dt.NewRow
            myrow("FromPARC") = V1
            dt.Rows.Add(myrow)
            msg = msg & V1 & " -999 "
        End If
    Next

    msg = msg & "------------------------------------------------------------------ -999 "
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        check = False
        For Each rw As GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
            V1 = row.Cells(0).Text
            V2 = rw.Cells(0).Text
            V1 = Replace(V1, " ", "")
            If V1 = V2 Then
                check = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If check = False Then
            myrow = dt.NewRow
            myrow("FromJDE") = V1
            dt.Rows.Add(myrow)
            msg = msg & V1 & " -999 "
        End If
    Next

    GridView3.DataSource = dt
    GridView3.DataBind()

    msg = Replace(msg, "-999", "<br />")

    ' used to output for testing
    Label1.Text = msg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a data table and clone one of the grid view sources. Then add records as needed to the data table and set a new grid view with the data source as this table.  Something like..

```
Dim GridView3 as New GridView 
Dim missingRecords as New Datatable
missingRecords = GridView1.dataSource.Clone()
'add your records here
GridView3.dataSource = missingRecords
GridView3.dataBind()
```

Comment: thanks luke for your quick response. I tried what you suggested but i am using gridviews not datagridviews. i have the GridView3 already declared in the aspx page, but after i do the gridview3.datasource = missingRecords the gridview does not display anything.

Comment: I'm sorry I believe you need GridView3.dataBind() as well

Comment: i put it in there before i ran the code and still got nothing. i edited my post to show the code for a better way to show what i am doing

Comment: I would try setting a break point inside the "If V1 = V2" if-statement to make sure some records meet the criteria.  If that's not the problem, make sure the rows are being added to the data table in the if statement and that the data table is set as the gridView's data source after all records have been added.

Comment: there are alike values in both columns. i just need to output them in two different columns of GridView3 together and then if there is no alike values they will be in the corresponding column with a blank in the opposite column of GridView3. i tried moving some things around and it runs through the code i added from you but it is still not displaying GridView3.